# Is it possible to get another person's UI in Google Apps Script?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script when you use the property: `DocumentApp.getUi()`, it gets the UI of the person who is using it. If you used `DocumentApp.getUi().alert()`, then it would send an alert to the person who is using the script. I am wondering if there is maybe a way to alert another person's UI in Google Apps Script and not the person who is using the script. Here is a sample of my code:

```
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
          .removeViewer(userName.getResponseText())
          .removeEditor(userName.getResponseText());

DocumentApp.getUi()
          .alert("Your access is being removed.")
```

Now it would be wonderful and imagine all the possibilities if that were possible! Someone please help!

Comment: So what you want is, for example, that if I'm viewing the doc, you would get a UI alert?

Comment: yes. I can't find anything online though, is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to access the UI of any browser except the one which invoked the function. This is also why time driven triggers cannot display UI modals (they are executing nonlocally).